# PHP artisan looping array error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to get some data into a mySql database. The first line gets added however the others dont. Basically it doesn't loop and so it shows an error saying :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry xxxxx

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call(xSeeder::class);
    $this->call(xxSeeder::class);

    Artisan::call('cache:clear', []);
}
}
```

It runs the xSeeder which is shown below and the "AA", "a" gets updated into the database. However, it does not update "BB", "B" and tries to update "AA", "a" again.

```
<?php
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DepartmentSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{

    /** @var Roles */
    $default_role_list = [
        ['display_name' => 'AA', 'name' => 'a'],
        ['display_name' => 'BB', 'name' => 'b'],
        ['display_name' => 'CC', 'name' => 'c'],

    ];

    foreach ($default_role_list as $role) {
        Role::create([
            'name'         => $role['name'],
            'display_name' => $role['display_name'],
        ]);
    }

}
}
```

I have tried another code which is:

```
<?php
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class DepartmentSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{

    /** @var Roles */
    $default_role_list = array(
                             0 => array("display_name"=>"AA","name"=>"a"),
                             1 => array("display_name"=>"BB","name"=>"b"),
                             2 => array("display_name"=>"CC","name"=>"c"),
                              );
    $default_role_list_count =0;
    foreach ($default_role_list as $role) {
        Role::create( array(
            'name'         => $role[$default_role_list_count]['name'],
            'display_name' => $role[$default_role_list_count]['display_name'],
        ));
        $default_role_list_count++;
    }

}
}?>
```

This shows error:

> [ErrorException]  Undefined offset: 0

Comment: You might have `unique` constraint on the columns. Try checking the existence of the Role, if exists do `update` else do `create`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
    <?php
    use App\Role;
    use App\Permission;
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    class DepartmentSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {

            /** @var Roles */
            $default_role_list = array(
                array("display_name"=>"AA","name"=>"a"),
                array("display_name"=>"BB","name"=>"b"),
                array("display_name"=>"CC","name"=>"c"),
            );
            foreach ($default_role_list as $role) {
                Role::create( $role );
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou, now it skips it. It moves onto the next seeder

Comment: Sorry i did read your full question, i already update the answer